# What is wrong with my primes number program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_divisible(n, primes):
    for i in range(1, len(primes)):
        if n % primes[i] == 0:
            return True
    return False
primes = []
def find_primes(N):
    for j in range(1, N):
        if is_divisible(j, primes) == False:
            primes.append(j)
        return primes
print(find_primes(200))
```

It should tell if a number is prime. And just prints 1.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number. Your program should start from 2.  for j in range(2, N).

Comment: If i put in 2 it just prints 2

Comment: you probably also want to implement the `yield` statement too. As soon is you find your first prime, you return

Comment: `for prime in primes` instead of `for i in range(len(primes))`! Also, make your divisibility check easier to read: `if not is_divisible(j, primes):`

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is the indentation of the return statement. Here's your code fixed up:

```
def is_divisible(n, primes):
    for i in range(0, len(primes)):
        if n % primes[i] == 0:
            return True
    return False

def find_primes(N):
    primes = []
    for j in range(2, N):
        if is_divisible(j, primes) == False:
            primes.append(j)
    return primes
```

Also avoid globals if you don't have to. find_primes doesnt need to access a global primes list it can declare it locally. Also, notice the range in find_primes that starts at 2 since every number is divisible by 1. Also, indendation matters. In both functions you do not iterate over the entire loop before returning the output (in find_primes) or the default (in is_divisible)

Comment: shouldn't the range go from 0 to len(primes) in the is_divisible function?

Comment: Beat me here as well. But, there are a couple other problems here that you should address: He's passing an empty list to `is_divisible` the first time, so it will *always* append the first number without looking at it. Then, it iterates from `1` instead of from `0`. Finally, `primes` should probably be local to `find_primes`, not module-level. And you should probably mention the change to the starting index in `find_primes`, as well :)

Comment: thanks @HenryKeiter sometimes there is too much to fix in one function :) I'm getting there though and upvoted your comment for what it's worth

Answer (score 1):

All numbers are divisible by 1. When your program checks if 1 is a prime it determines yes it is so it appends it to the array. Then, when it checks if the next number 2 is divisible by any of the existing primes it says yes, it is divisible by 1 therefore it is not a prime etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first number you add is 1, every number is divisible by one and therefore is_divisible(x,1)== True and no number other then 1 is appended to the primes list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return primes` line is inside the for loop, which means that it just check the first number (i.e. `1`), and returns the result of that single calculation.

Your program should instead return the primes after looking at all the number, not just at the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the remark above (your program should start from 2), you do not want to return until you've completed the 'for j in range((2),N): ' loop. That is, you need to dedent the 'return primes' statement.